# Handlebars.js If not working as expect

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

Insanity check, can someone confirm that mainLocation should return "yes". For some reason it returning "no".

Here is my code.

```
<script id="Templates" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div id="RowExpand{{id}}" class="collapse">
  {{#if mainLocation}}
    yes - Some content here...
  {{else}}
    no - Some content here...
  {{/if}}      
</div>
</script>
```

This is the json data in firebug.

```
address     "5862 Vincent Blvd."
city        "Santa Monica"
state       "CA"
zipcode     "90452"
mainlocation    true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case other are having the same issue. This is how resolved my problem. I created a custom handlebars helper like so.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ismainlocation", function(mainlocation) {
 if(mainlocation){
   return "Yes";
 }
 else{
   return "No";
 }
});
```

And I changed my script template like so.

```
<script id="Templates" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <div id="RowExpand{{id}}" class="collapse">
 {{ismainlocation mainlocation}}     
 </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your data context for this template?

To make this work, you could wrap the section in a with block helper

```
In your html file:
 <head>
  ...
 </head>
 <body>
   {{> example}}
 <body>

<template name="example">
  {{#with data}}
    {{#if mainLocation}}
      html code
    {{else}}
      other html code
    {{/if}}
  {{/with}}
</template>


In your js file: 
Template.example.helpers({
   data: function () {
     return {mainLocation: true};
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm fairly new to handlebars and I'm not if I'm putting your script in the correctly location. This is what I've tried: <script id="Templates" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div id="RowExpand{{id}}" class="collapse">
  <template name="example">
  {{#with data}}
    {{#if mainLocation}}
      html
    {{else}}
      other html
    {{/if}}
  {{/with}}
  </template>

  Template.example.helpers({
    data: function () {
      return {mainLocation: true};
  }
});      
</div>
</script> and it didn't work. What's am I doing wrong? thank you

Comment: If you are working on a Meteor project. You wouldn't need script tag.  I am going to modify my answer to show you

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using Meteor.